# Execution in Background

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I don't know whether I am right or wrong but just want to know  can I run selenium webdriver scripts in background. I want to give some more explanation about this as
I have one script which will launch a browser (IE or FF) enter some data in some edit fields and click on some buttons. 
Is it possible in background. If not can you please suggest me any tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try exploring [htmlunitdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#htmlunit-driver)